# g'mara about David's conception

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, pregnancy-birth, king-david, divorce

Where's the *g'mara* about *Yishay*'s divorce (or was it separation?) and *David*'s conception, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the source is not a Gemara. The source is a Medrash:

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32637&st=&pgnum=205

ב"ילקוט המכירי" לתהלים קי"ח, כ"ב מובא:

"ישי פירש מאשתו שלוש שנים. לאחר שלוש שנים אמר לשפחתו תקני עצמך הלילה כד שתיכנסי אלי בגט שחרור (רצה להכשיר זרעו מפסול מואבי, שעדין היו עוררין על ההלכה 'מואבי ולא מואבית'), הלכה ואמרה לגבירתה.... (הסכימו ביניהן). לערב, כשיאמר לי סגרי הדלת תכנסי את ואני אצא וכך עשתה. עשתה אם דוד עמו הלילה ונתעברה מדוד. בקשו בניה להרגה ואת בנה דוד, אמר להם ישי הניחו לו ויהיה לנו משועבד ורועה צאן.

Comment: Thank you! Paragraph 28, though, not 22, in the http://hebrewbooks.org/32637 version.

Comment: But _Yalkut Ham'chiri_ is a _yalkut_, a compilation; any idea of an earlier source?

Comment: The editor/publisher of this edition http://hebrewbooks.org/32636 9same as the one I linked to in the comment above, but the first volume) includes at its start a list of midrashic sources for the _yalkut_, and lists no source for this paragraph.

Comment: Another point: I've also learned _Yishay_'s reason for separating from his wife was _Moavis_, but the _M'chiri_ doesn't say so, so there must be some other source, no?

Comment: מובא בתורת המנחה (פ' בשלח דרוש כ"ג) לרבינו יעקב סקלי (מתלמידי הרשב"א) וכ"ה בילקוט מכירי (תהלים קיח:כח) ובמדרש דוד הנגיד (שמות עמ' קכב-קכג) ובכלי יקר (שמואל א' טז:יא) ששמע מפי רבינו שלמה אלקביץ. ספר הקושיות ס' קנ"א. וגם הובא בחיד"א (מראית העין פסחים קיט., שמחת הרגל על הגש"פ ד"ה אנה ה' כי אני עבדך, ברכי יוסף או"ח ס' ר"מ) עץ יוסף (ויקרא רבה פי"ד ס"ה), בן יהוידע (פסחים קיט.), ובמועדים וזמנים (ח"ז ס' רמ"ב).