# Did Yishai sin?

Tags: marriage, sin, sexuality, maseches-shabbos

Did Yishai sin? The gemarah (shabbat 55b) states pretty clearly that he did not; however, the midrash ([Yalkut HaMakiri](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32637&st=&pgnum=205), [cited here](http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/280331/jewish/Nitzevet-Mother-of-David.htm)) seems to indicate that he separated from his wife for an extended period of time, which is forbidden. How do we resolve these two statements?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7099/gmara-about-davids-conception

Answer (score 1):

According to the version cited in [Gershon Gold's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7103/1569), the reason why he separated was because they hadn't revealed the law of מואבי ולא מואבית, and his ancestress was from Mo'av (meaning he was forbidden from marrying a Jew). I also saw this version quoted in Sefer HaToda'ah in the month of Sivan, but I don't have the book in front of me to check again.

Comment: pretty sure that is still a sin. he can divorce her but just because he has a safek doesn't give him the right to refuse onah. he should've gotten a psak, no?

Comment: @PM What makes you think he didn't get a psak? Maybe his psak was to wait until the dispute over מואבי ולא מואבית was resolved

Comment: I ain't no rabbi but being over an aveira does not a psak make